# Need to Implement Single Sign On in PHP

Tags: php, symfony, single-sign-on, openid

I have read a lot of document regarding this, Few of which are as follows

http://www.opengroup.org/security/sso/sso_intro.htm
http://www.authenticationworld.com/Single-Sign-On-Authentication/
http://merbist.com/2012/04/04/building-and-implementing-a-single-sign-on-solution/
https://wiki.queensu.ca/display/itsd/Single+Sign-On

I know the concept now but my client already has a systems build which has there own authentication system already in place and working and now i need to implement this concept for him all over his application

He has given me the access for only one of the main application where i can implement this but now the problem is, Client is not ready for the access of other application,
So is there any way where i can implement some plugging and ask the client to call this every time for the authentication and implement the single sign on.

It would be really helpful if anyone can give me the basic building block or Steps to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You can make SimpleSamlPHP as your IDP to implement Single Sign On to your client application. SimpleSamlPHP(IDP will take care of the authentication).This is light weight IDP Where you can store the user info and Payload as configuration file.

Refer the below link to configure the SimpleSamlPHP.

https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/